# conditions for populist badge

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm a little confused as to the conditions for the populist badge.  My understanding is that any answer that has a score of at least 11 and more than double the accepted answer earns it.  But how come, for example, @chaos doesn't have one for [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11155/is-it-acceptable-to-nest-parentheses)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The score of the *accepted answer* must be at least 11, and so the badge-earner's answer must have a score of 23 or more.

There's an ambiguity in the description of *Populist* for where the prepositional phrase ("with a score of more than 10") adjoins into the sentence.  This is the correct parse:

- Answer outscored [an accepted answer with score of more than 10] by more than 2x

When in doubt, always check the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) on the meta Meta.